# How to store results from procedure in a new (individual) text file in SQL Server for each execution

Tags: sql-server

Below is my code which is printing my sql result to text file.
My problem is : how to create new text file for each execution, instead of append result to same text file already created?

I am trying to add >> but it only append result in the same text.

need help please, it not the duplicate question because, the old question show how to write result in the same text file but for my problem i need to create new one, and don't want to overwrite the old text file.

```
Declare @fn varchar(8000) = 'C:\Tmp\log\out.txt';
Declare @cmd varchar(8000);

DECLARE @viewObjectIds TABLE (object_id INT);
INSERT INTO @viewObjectIds
  SELECT o.object_id
    FROM sys.objects AS o
      WHERE o.type = 'V';

DECLARE view_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
   SELECT object_id FROM @viewObjectIds;

OPEN view_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM view_cursor INTO @object_id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 SELECT @command =
   'EXECUTE sp_refreshview '''
   + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id))
   + ''';';

 PRINT @command;
 SELECT @cmd  = 'echo '+ @command + ' >> '+ @fn + '' ;         
 exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
  FETCH NEXT FROM view_cursor INTO @object_id;
END
```

Comment: Can you add the stored procedure, that will make it easier to help you

Comment: The solution is to dynamically create a new filename each time you run the stored procedure and write to that file. If you provide the source for your stored procedure, people here can help you.

Comment: i just added my stored procedure

Comment: my question  is different because i dont want to store pocedure in same text file but for each execution a want new text file . thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could concat CURRENT_TIMESTAMP onto the out.txt filename. Simple solution that will create a new file for every execution.

EDIT:

```
Declare @fn varchar(8000) = 'C:\Tmp\log\' + convert(varchar(25), current_timestamp, 120) + 'out.txt';
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but can u give me an exemple please i tried it but it seems that i don't know how i can use this function with the file name. thanks

Comment: Declare @fn varchar(8000) = 'C:\Tmp\log\' + convert(varchar(25), current_timestamp, 120) + 'out.txt';